# How to set firebase crashltycs in One apps with multiple firebase project

Tags: java, android, firebase, crashlytics, google-fabric

I have an android application with multiple firebase project (like production and develop). Previously, my application was connected to fabric crashlytics. What is the best step to migrate the crashlytics from fabric to firebase?

I have already tried migrate with linked from fabric to one of firebase project (I linked to production), and it worked. Besides sending crash report to the firebase console, the application is still send to fabric. Should I delete the old fabric crashlytics code? 
I also tried removing fabric api key from AndroidManifest.xml, but the result is my application didnt send any report to firebase or fabric. 
Can I get some explanation about the correct step?

Answer (score 1):

You can consult the documentation.

https://firebase.google.com/docs/crashlytics/get-started?authuser=1#android .

The documentation is very well done :)

Answer (score 0):

Genrate google-services.json file in your firebase console, then add it to your project. Also you can use different google-services.json files for different build types or flavors in your project.

google-services.json file contains keys and necessary information for syncing analytics, crashlytics and other services with your app.